# How do I delete a partial package in OpenBSD

Tags: package-management, openbsd

While upgrading, I tried to add a package that was already there and due to some error, a partial package got created - partial-gnutls.

When I try to delete this partial package, I get these errors:

```
File /usr/local/share/locale/cs/LC_MESSAGES/pkg.qX9SMkCPZb does not exist                                                            
File /usr/local/share/locale/de/LC_MESSAGES/pkg.Dfpr8PbT3X does not exist                                                            
File /usr/local/share/locale/en@boldquot/LC_MESSAGES/pkg.wIH7fQJbhK does not exist                                                   
File /usr/local/share/locale/en@quot/LC_MESSAGES/pkg.c8llMmPSGl does not exist                                                       
Read failed: Input/output error at /usr/libdata/perl5/OpenBSD/md5.pm line 59
```

I checked the source code. It is some coe that adds a file into some data structure (most probably, it is finding out which files to delete) and it fails to do so because the file is no longer there.

How do I get rid of this partial package?

Answer (score 4):

You could try creating an empty file for each of the files listed, e.g.:

```
touch /usr/local/share/locale/cs/LC_MESSAGES/pkg.qX9SMkCPZb
```

and so on.  Once the files are there use `pkg_delete -qq` to delete without comparing recorded checksums.

If that doesn't work, `/var/db/pkg/<pkg-name>/+CONTENTS` lists the package's contents and locations where files have been installed, so could could also use that information to delete the files manually and then remove the offending `/var/db/pkg/<pkg-name>` directory.